# JMeter 4 remote testing in cloud with SSL keystore

Tags: performance, ssl, jmeter, cloud, keystore

I am setting up JMeter 4.0 for load testing in the cloud (GCE). I am creating VM images for the master and slave with the only difference being the slaves run jmeter-server on boot. I ran `bin/create-rmi-keystore.sh` per http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl and ensured the .jks file is on the master/client and all the slaves. 
Now, when I create multiple slave instances (new slave IPs), the load test fails due to SSL errors -

`Configuring remote engine: 10.150.0.11
error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Failed to configure 10.150.0.11`

Can I avoid having to manually regenerate the keystore every time I plan a test run?

Comment: As a workaround I added server.rmi.ssl.disable=true in jmeter.properties to disable ssl for rmi

Comment: Can you show full jmeter.log after setting level to debug in log4j2.xml ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have created `rmi_keystore.jks` on your `master` , copy that on your slave's bin directory. You can restart `jmeter-server.bat` on slave after that.